# C++ string library error: string subscript out of range

Tags: c++, string, vector

```
string *parse(string str,int from){
int i=0,n=0,j,k;
i=j=from;
string *data=new string[6];
while(str[i]){
    if(str[i]==' '){
        for(k=0;k<(i-j-1);k++){
            data[n][k]=str[j+k]; << Error takes place here
        }
        data[n][k]='\0';
        j=i;
        n++;
    }
    i++;
}
return data;
}
```

Thanks for your help. I tried to debug but without success, what am I missing?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: `data` starts with 0 length, `data[n][k]` out of boundry

Comment: Are you trying to split string by space?

Comment: yes im trying to split by space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that elements `data[i]` of the `data` array all have the length of zero. That is why the assignment `data[n][k]` is always outside of `data[n]`'s range.

One way of fixing this would be using concatenation:

```
data[n] += str[j+k];
```

A better approach would be eliminating the loop altogether, and using [`substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) member function of `std::string` instead: it lets you cut out a portion of `str` knowing the desired length and the starting position.

In addition, you are returning a pointer to a local array, which is undefined behavior. You should replace an array with a `vector<string>`, and add items to it using `push_back`.

Finally, you need to push the final word when the `str` does not end in a space.

Here is your modified program that uses the above suggestions:

```
vector<string> parse(string str,int from){
    int i=from, j=from;
    vector<string> data;
    while(str[i]){
        if(str[i]==' '){
            data.push_back(str.substr(j, i-j+1));
            j=i+1;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (j != str.size()) {
        data.push_back(str.substr(j));
    }
    return data;
}
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/BxiQgV).

Comment: Might have been worth doing some of the legwork with string::find

Comment: @kfsone You are right, there are ways to optimize this code for better use of the library. I wanted to keep as much of OP's code structure as possible, so I kept the loop the way it was.

Answer (score 1):

`data` starts with `0` length, data[n][k] out of boundry. `data[n][k]='\0'` is not correct way of using C++ string and `string *` is considered of bad practice.

To separate a string by space, try:

```
  #include <string>
  #include <vector>
  #include <sstream>

  std::string data("hi hi hi hi hi");
  std::stringstream ss(data);
  std::string word;

  std::vector<std::string> v;
  while(std::getline(ss, word, ' '))
  {
    v.push_back(word);
  }
```

Comment: I dont want to use other libraries

Comment: @MikeL that's not other libraries, it's standard C++ library. The way you use like C operation loses the point of using string